# Organization of commands in makefile

Tags: shell, docker, makefile, docker-compose

I have the following command which runs integration tests:

```
run-it:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose-tests.yml pull && \
    docker-compose -f docker-compose-tests.yml up --build & \
    sleep 150s && dotnet test --filter TestCategory=Integration.Tests $(SOLUTION) ; docker-compose -f docker-compose-tests.yml down
```

I want:

1. pull all containers
2. run docker compose in background
3. run integrations tests in 150 seconds.

But it looks that test start running before the `pull` command is completed.

[image]

I want 1 point run first, then 2 started and 3 start in 150 seconds after 2 is started.

Comment: It seems like the 150-second wait must be to allow `docker-compose` to finish its work, but if that's what you're trying to do, then why put `docker-compose` in the background at all?  That leaves you vulnerable to failures in the event that it takes longer than you expect to pull and build the containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before worrying about make you should ensure that you can run the commands correctly from the shell prompt.  In this case you're misunderstanding how the background token `&` works; it applies to the entire previous section of the command.  Basically, you're running the equivalent of this:

```
( docker-compose -f docker-compose-tests.yml pull && \
  docker-compose -f docker-compose-tests.yml up --build ) & \
sleep 150s && ...
```

Since you've put *both* the `pull` and the `up` into the background, the sleep and tests start running concurrently to the `pull`.

Try adding some parens to put the backgrounded process into a subshell:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-tests.yml pull && \
  ( docker-compose -f docker-compose-tests.yml up --build & ) && \
sleep 150s && ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it.